# How to query multiple times and close the connection at the end?

Tags: mysql, r, database-connection

I'd like to open a connection to mysql database and retrieve data with different queries. Do I need to close the connection every time I fetch the data or is there a better way to query multiple times and close the connection only at the end?

Currently I do this:

```
db = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='1234', dbname='my_db', host='localhost')

query1=dbSendQuery(db, "select * from table1")
data1 = fetch(query1, n=10000)
query2=dbSendQuery(db, "select * from table2")  ##ERROR !
```

and I get the error message:

> Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     RS-DBI driver: (connection with pending rows, close resultSet before continuing)

Now if I clear the result with **dbClearResult(query1)** I need to redo the connection **(dbConnect...)**

Is there a better/efficient way to fetch everything first instead of open/close every time?

Comment: you need to clear the result set before executing another query. read ?dbSendQuery, specifically the Details part. dbGetQuery is better suited for what you're trying to do, look @Stuples answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `dbGetQuery(...)` instead of using `dbSendQuery(...)` and `fetch()` like this

```
db = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='1234', dbname='my_db', host='localhost')

query1=dbGetQuery(db, "select * from table1")
query2=dbGetQuery(db, "select * from table1")
```

From the help page:

> The function ‘dbGetQuery’ does all these in one operation (submits the statement, fetches all output records, and clears the result set).